# Chrome Native Messaging - Host App should be packed with extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-native-messaging, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I am new to Chrome Extension.
I have a project to create a chrome extension that can help our web app to communicate with other team's desktop applications.

So I know I need to use native messaging, so I need to create a native host. But I am confused about where I should keep the native host? Can it be packed with the chrome extension? So when I publish the extension, the other team can install the extension, then they will have the native host?

Or I need to zip the native host app, and send it to the other team?

Also, the examples about native messaging I found so far are all for Chrome Manifest V2, is there any example for native messaging in Manifest V3? What should I put into host_permission for nativeMessaging? I put nativeMessaging in Manifest V3 and it gave me an error.

Comment: You cannot distribute native messaging hosts from Chrome web store. They have to be manually downloaded and installed by users

Comment: So in order for other teams to have the ability to communicate to our web app. They need to download the whole extension and native host together? I thought I will publish an extension to chrome extension, so users can just find the extension in chrome store, then they only need to download the native host, is that right?

Comment: @wOxxOm has answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host app is a separate download on a separate [public] server.

1. The users will install the extension from the web store.
2. The extension tries chrome.runtime.connectNative, and on failure it opens a page showing how to download the app from some external URL and how to install/register it.

ManifestV3 doesn't change anything for nativeMessaging. There's nothing it needs in `host_permissions`: the term `host` here means `site`. To adapt the examples you'll only need to change a couple of fields as explained in the  [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: When I tried to migrate to V3, it gave me an error saying failed to load backgound.js. Because of this, I am also not able to inspect the background.js to debug this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your manifest.json and background.js in a new question.